# MONO return connection refused while using net.tcp binding

Tags: linux, wcf, service, mono, net.tcp

I have a WCF project and it works well in windows and these days I'm trying to port the server to linux. Unfortunately, I found net.tcp binding is not working, while basicHttp works fine.

When my client connect to my net.tcp(NetTcpBinding.SecurityMode.None) service, it always return "connection refused", but in fact the port is still listening.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Solved. Post it here cause cant reply my own question so soon.
The problem is really weird, it's you CAN'T use localhost as your listen address in mono.
So, change service address to a specify IP, all things done.

Comment: please report the problem in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=275

Basically, if you ask to listen on "localhost", only connections from the local machine are allowed. This is different from what .NET does.

(Mono also refuses to let you use "0.0.0.0", which .NET allows.)

The bug is marked as "fixed", but I don't know in what version...